# How to modify a large image's rgb pixels?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, pixel, rgb

I've this code which works fine, I'm creating a canvas and adjust the RGB values of a picture with range inputs. My only problem is that the image is super big and it slows down the code greately. If I set the canvas width and height the picture will come out blury. How can I fix it, so I have a high quality (or higher quality it doesnt have to be the same quality as the original picture) image and my code isn't super slow?

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import cityImage from "../../assets/city.jpg"

export default function MainGlass({ cursorPosition, glassPosition, zoomValue, lock, rgbValue, mouseOver }) {

  const [lockedCursorPosition, setLockedCursorPosition] = useState(null);
  const [lockedGlassPosition, setLockedGlassPosition] = useState(null);
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState();

  const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState('');
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const [originalImageData, setOriginalImageData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
      setOriginalImageData(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height));
      setImageSrc(canvas.toDataURL());
    };
    // Specify the path to your image relative to the public folder
    img.src = cityImage;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (imageSrc) {
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.putImageData(originalImageData, 0, 0); // Reset canvas to the original image
      applyColorToImage(ctx, rgbValue.r, rgbValue.g, rgbValue.b);
      setImageSrc(canvas.toDataURL());
    }
  }, [rgbValue]);

  const applyColorToImage = (ctx, r, g, b) => {
    if (!ctx) return; // Ensure that the context is available

    const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    const data = imageData.data;
    const len = data.length;
    const rFactor = r / 100;
    const gFactor = g / 100;
    const bFactor = b / 100;

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
      data[i] = Math.min(255, data[i] * rFactor);         // Red channel
      data[i + 1] = Math.min(255, data[i + 1] * gFactor); // Green channel
      data[i + 2] = Math.min(255, data[i + 2] * bFactor); // Blue channel
    }

    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  };


  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!lock) {
      setLockedCursorPosition({ x: cursorPosition.x, y: cursorPosition.y });
      setLockedGlassPosition({ x: glassPosition.x, y: glassPosition.y });
    }
    if(mouseOver){
      setDisplay('flex')
    }
    if (!mouseOver && !lock) {
      setDisplay('none')
    }
  }, [cursorPosition, glassPosition, lock]);
  
  const styles = {
    '--x': lock ? (lockedGlassPosition ? `${lockedGlassPosition.x}px` : null) : `${glassPosition.x}px`,
    '--y': lock ? (lockedGlassPosition ? `${lockedGlassPosition.y}px` : null) : `${glassPosition.y}px`,
    'left': lock ? (lockedCursorPosition ? `${lockedCursorPosition.x}px` : null) : `${cursorPosition.x}px`,
    'top': lock ? (lockedCursorPosition ? `${lockedCursorPosition.y}px` : null) : `${cursorPosition.y}px`,
    backgroundImage: `url(${imageSrc})`,
    'display':display,
    '--m': zoomValue,
  }
  return (
    <div className='main-glass'
    style={styles}>
      <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={{ display: 'none' }} width="768" height="432" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've tried adjusting these values but it ruins the picture.

Comment: I don't think anything else but reducing the amount of pixels, _can_ help here much. _"If I set the canvas width and height the picture will come out blury."_ - maybe the user can still "work" with that to change the colors - and after they are satisfied with the result, you then apply the chosen parameters to the full-size image _once_ ...?